# Java: For loop not printing the last iteration

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I am currently trying to make a simple program that will calculate the number of vowels in multiple sentences. The input looks like this: 
6 
Emily jumped high
Alex did not jump
Phillip hates jumping 
The red dragon can fly
Sandwiches are nice 
I like the sun

The number indicates how many lines there are. My problem is that when I print out the results, the last line gets ignored. So the program prints out 5 ints, rather than 6. I've been playing around with it for ages and I just can't seem to get my head around the issue.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int cases = in.nextInt(); //how many lines there are 
String a; 
int vowels = 0;
int length; //length of a line
char temp;
in.nextLine(); //skips first line of the input, as this declares how many lines there are

for (int i = 0; i <= cases; i++) 
{
    a = in.nextLine();
    length = a.length();
    //System.out.println(a);
    for (int b = 0; b < length; b++)
    {
        temp = a.charAt(b);
        if (temp == 'a' || temp == 'e' || temp == 'i' || temp == 'o' || temp == 'u')
        {
            vowels++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(vowels);
    vowels=0;
}
```

Comment: Note that `i` should start at 1, or you get 7 iterations in your example .

Comment: Could you include the expected and the actuall output aswell, since i don´t really get what your problem is at the moment.

Comment: @KevinEsche the expected output is  4 4 6 5 7 5, where as the actual output is 4 4 6 5 7

Comment: I suggest you step through your code in you debugger to see what is going wrong, reading your code it should iterate 7 times for 0,1,2,3,4,5,6

Comment: the output is 6 
Emily jumped high
4
Alex did not jump
4
Phillip hates jumping 
6
The red dragon can fly
5
Sandwiches are nice
7
I like the sun 
4

0

Comment: Did you do any changes and are you sure that you are using this version of the code, since it seems to produce the ouput that you are expecting.

Comment: @KevinEsche Not for me. I get a `NoSuchElementException` at `java.util.Scanner.nextLine()` when I use input redirection.

Comment: @PhillipSchikora How are you running your program? Does your poem exist in a file? Eg: `java Vowel < poem.txt` Are you pasting the input into the terminal when the application runs?

Comment: We have learned now, from OP's answer, that the input didn't have a final `new line`: "press enter to make the last one show up". I suggest this question should be closed due to typo.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason when I posted the input, it would automatically show me the first 5 ints, I then just had to press enter to make the last one show up. So apparently hitting enter is now also one of the skills I've acquired ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have extra step in loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= cases; i++)
```

The loop you need is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < cases; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looping for cases+1 times ie 7 times. You should either use

```
for (int i = 0; i < cases; i++)
```

or

```
for (int i = 1; i <= cases; i++)
```

Otherwise your code will print the expected output.

Answer (score -1):

Your code is work fine. Only one problem you need change `i <= case` to `i < case`. You can use this website for testing your code with std input.
https://ideone.com/Ud3MWt